# What is the Linux equivalent of Window's PATH

Tags: linux, java, linux-mint

In Windows I set my PATH to point to my JDK bin folder so I can easily run commands that involve Java. What is the equivalent of this for Linux distros?

I am using Linux Mint 13.

Comment: Related: [What are PATH and other environment variables and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/q/284342/150988)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the variable ....PATH :-)

If you want to see it, just launch a terminal and type : `echo $PATH`

If you need to change it, launch a terminal and type : `export PATH=$PATH:/my/new/path`

If you need to change the path definitely, add the export line in the `/home/username/.bashrc`.